# Glassfish Maven Deploy Plugin - Deployment Failure

Tags: maven, glassfish-3, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-glassfish-plugin

Getting an exception while trying to deploy my maven-based application into **Glassfish 3.1.2.2**.

I'm using **org.glassfish.maven.plugin** for deployment.

Here's my source files:

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${glassfish.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <glassfishDirectory>${local.glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
        <echo>true</echo>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <autoCreate>true</autoCreate>
        <glassfishDirectory>${local.glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
        <user>${local.glassfish.user}</user>
        <passwordFile>${local.glassfish.passfile}</passwordFile>
        <domain>
            <name>${local.glassfish.domain}</name>
            <httpPort>${local.glassfish.httpPort}</httpPort>
            <adminPort>${local.glassfish.adminPort}</adminPort>
        </domain>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
            </component>
        </components>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository/>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <usePluginRegistry/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <servers/>
    <mirrors/>
    <proxies/>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>glassfish-context</id>
            <properties>
                <local.glassfish.home>/home/talha/glassfish-3.1.2.2</local.glassfish.home>
                <local.glassfish.user>admin</local.glassfish.user>
                <local.glassfish.domain>dms</local.glassfish.domain>
                <local.glassfish.httpPort>8080</local.glassfish.httpPort>
                <local.glassfish.adminPort>4848</local.glassfish.adminPort>
                <local.glassfish.passfile>
                    ${local.glassfish.home}/glassfish/domains/${local.glassfish.domain}/master-password
                </local.glassfish.passfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>glassfish-context</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

**Full Stacktrace**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project dms: Deployment of /home/talha/IdeaProjects/DMS/target/DMS.war failed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project dms: Deployment of /home/talha/IdeaProjects/DMS/target/DMS.war failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Deployment of /home/talha/IdeaProjects/DMS/target/DMS.war failed.
    at org.glassfish.maven.plugin.command.AsadminCommand.execute(AsadminCommand.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.maven.plugin.DeployGlassfishMojo.doExecute(DeployGlassfishMojo.java:66)
    at au.net.ocean.maven.plugin.OceanMojo.execute(OceanMojo.java:67)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is almost the exact same as mine with 2 exceptions.

1. I'm specifying a passwordFile in my user home with a file name of `.asadminpass`
2. I have an `<executions>` element defined that breaks the build if removed.

```xml
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>none</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>deploy</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <debug>true</debug>
      <terse>false</terse>
      <autoCreate>false</autoCreate>
      <domain>
        <name>${local.glassfish.domain}</name>
        <httpPort>${local.glassfish.httpPort}</httpPort>
        <adminPort>${local.glassfish.adminPort}</adminPort>
      </domain>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

If neither of those help, try including your glassfish log file in the question.  That should indicate what failed.

Comment: Accepted?  What was the problem?